# ActionBarSherlock Bottom Menu - Tablet

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, tablet, android-menu

**Problem :** *Menu Not displayed in the bottom (displayed in top !)*

**ASB Library :** *The last version*

**Device :** *Tablet*

**Android OS:** *4.2*

**menu_bottom.xml :**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- SplitActionBar Menu-->
     <item
            android:id="@+id/aproximite"            
            android:title="A Proximite"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
            android:id="@+id/qrcode"                  
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
            android:title="Lecteur QR"/>

</menu>
```

**Manifest :**

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            android:label="@string/app_name">                                              
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
// Comment ...    ...               
    public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements TabListener {
```

...

```
//Comment
    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME); 
            setupTabs();
```

...

```
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_bottom, menu);
           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

Comment: For ref : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/actionbarsherlock/aBboXx69gnk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know (tested!) `splitActionBar` works only on phones, because the screen size is much smaller than tablets and it takes space at the bottom for extra space for your action items. On tablets, the screen size is much bigger and there is enough space for most of the action items, that's why your menu is placed on top.

Comment: i have the last version of facebook they use bottom menu ! (i have test it in my tablet !!)

Comment: but i'm not sur if they are items menu or a simple layout !!

Comment: the facebook app is not using split action bar, it's a custom controller which hide/show depending on it parent's scroll.

Comment: can you provide me a link to do it :)

Comment: i have an observation all my 3 tabs are becoming (Drop-down Navigation) and the bottom menu was adding into the left of my top actionbar ?

Comment: Here is tutorial for scrolling tricks : https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks . As for your second question, it really depends on what actually are you trying to achieve, the type of action items and what are their functionality. It is more a design implementation than coding in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in your fragments?

Comment: i use SherlockFragmentActivity  .. so setHasOptionsMenu() isnt a member method